# How can I get the adjacent areas of each element in NAME variable and make them into a data frame?

Tags: r, apply, r-sf

I have a shp file that contains the latitude and longitude of the area.I read it into R and name it county.It is just like this:

```
> class(county)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
> county <- data.frame(
  PAC <- c(110101, 110102, 110105)
  NAME <- c("dongcheng", "xicheng", "chaoyang")
  geometry <- c((((116.4058 39.96245, 116.4078 39))),(((116.3814 39.96006, 116.3805 39))),(((116.4803 40.07965, 116.4897 40))))
)
```

I use st_touches() to get the adjacent areas of each element in NAME variable.

```
> subcounty <- county[i, ]
> neighbor_counties <- function(subcounty){
  name <- st_touches(subcounty, county)
  county[unlist(name), ]$NAME
}
> neighbor_counties(county[1,])
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_touches assumes that they are planar
[1] "xicheng" "chaoyang" "fengtai"
```

However, there is an error when I use apply() to handle it.

```
> apply(county, 1, neighbor_counties)

Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "list"
Called from: st_geometry(x)
Error during wrapup: unimplemented type (29) in 'eval'

Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error during wrapup: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'unknown type #29'
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

How can I get the adjacent areas of each element in NAME variable and make them into a data frame?

Comment: Try `apply(as.matrix(county), 1, neighbor_counties)`.

Comment: I get the same error.